# Casting Date in WHERE condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

I am running a query to find a date between two dates, but the query isn't working as expected.

The date in my DB is saved in a `VARCHAR` field with values like `22-january-2015`.

How can I change `01-january-2015` to `01-01-2015`?

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date1, '%d-%M-%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(date2, '%d-%M-%Y'), 
 FROM table WHERE '22-11-2015' BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```

Comment: Try: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('01-january-2015', '%d-%M-%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> %M :  Month name (January-December)
>
> %m :    Month, numeric (00-12)

Please use `%m` instead of `%M`.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date1, '%d-%m-%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(date2, '%d-%m-%Y'), 
     FROM table Where '22-11-2015' BETWEEN  date1 AND date2
```

OR

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date1, '%d-%m-%Y'),'%d-%m-%Y'),
 DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date2, '%d-%m-%Y'),'%d-%m-%Y'), 
  FROM table Where '22-11-2015' BETWEEN  STR_TO_DATE(date1, '%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(date2, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: '22-11-2015' is dynamic date which will be a variable $date and have date '22-11-2015'

Comment: `Where '22-11-2015' BETWEEN  date1 AND date2` -> Can you explain in words what you mean by that?

Comment: its a dynamic date which i am searching between two dates my query is running all good my date is not converting to number as 01-january-2015 to 01-01-2015

Comment: what is the output you are getiing?

Comment: i am getting results  from all months as i am searching for 21-02-2015 it gives all records which have this date like 21 and 2015 in all months its not getting record from the given month.

Comment: you are really helping me here if you are allowed you can help me on skype my skype name is ahmad.saad.khn if you add me i can show you what problem i have